Compile errors when trying to share code between app clip and app which have different iOS versions
I have added an app clip with iOS version 17.4 to my main app of target 12.0. I am sharing code from the main app with the app clip by selecting both targets under the file's target membership.
In some places, this causes issues with deprecated code. Eg with this line:
"notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)"
Since including the app clip with the higher iOS version as a target for the file that contains the code, I am getting a compile error:
"'UIKeyboardWillHide' has been renamed to 'UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification', Replace 'UIKeyboardWillHide' with 'UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification'"
I thought using #availble would resolve this:
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    // For iOS 13.0 and later
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
} else {
    // For iOS 12.0
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

But I am still getting compile errors. If the main app scheme is selected, the errors occur in the first (if) statement, if the app clip is selected the errors occur in the second (else) statement.
I tried using
#if APPCLIP
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
#else
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
#endif 

But when the app clip scheme is selected the errors remain in the else statement.
I can obviously have two files, one for the app clip and one for the main app, but this is not ideal as it would mean if code changes need to made in the future they would have to be made twice.
Does anyone have a cleaner solution?

Might be time to consider updating your app's deployment target. iOS 12 is really old at this point. Do you really need to provide app updates to such an old version? A deployment target of iOS 13 (or even later) means you can fully support SF Symbols and scenes without worrying about iOS 12.
